# When is it OK to use the inversion in French language, except in interrogative and imperative?

Tags: inversion

- **Seul compte le fait** que je n’ai pas le droit d’échouer ! Je sais que la tâche est immense, mais elle en vaut la peine.

I think it would be *heavy* to form this sentence  with the subject "le fait" with the start of the sentence. Is this why the inversion is used?

Also, I think that an adverb or a preposition is always used a the start of a sentence in an inverted sentence.

- **Derrière** ... se cache (the subject).

What is the rule for determining when the inversion is OK to use or not?

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule for inversion but a series of specific cases - sentences beginning with adverbs (some of which make the inversion mandatory, others not), reported dialogues (*"dit-il"*), etc. In any case, I think it's safe to say that you'll mostly find inversion in formal/literary language and a few common expressions. In everyday speech, you almost never have to think about making an inversion or not.

Answer (score 2):

En français, vous **pouvez** presque toujours faire l'inversion.
Par exemple :

> Immense est la tâche.
>
> Derrière le vice se cache la vertu.

Souvent, et dans ces deux exemples, l'inversion rend 
le ton plus proverbial ou plus solennel.
Par exemple, si on veut dire qu'Alice se cache derrière Bernard
au sens physique, on dira plutôt :
>

> Alice se cache derrière Bernard

Mais si on veut le dire dans un sens métaphorique,
pour sous-entendre que Bernard agit sur ordre d'Alice,
on pourra dire :

> Derrière Bernard se cache Alice

La différence avec la forme interrogative est qu'alors
l'inversion devient **obligatoire**.
On devra donc poser la question :

> Alice se cache-t-elle derrière Bernard ?

Cela dit, "seul compte" est une expression toute faite
qu'on emploie quasiment toujours de cette manière :

> Seule compte ton implication.

Comme *Seule* évoque le sujet, ce mot agit quasiment comme un pronom.